Why is the comoving Hubble radius always increasing without inflation?
I have been told that the comoving Hubble radius $r_{H}(t)\equiv\frac{c}{\dot{a}}$ is increasing without inflation (and inflation was introduced as a period of time with decreasing $r_{H}$ in order to solve the horizon problem). On the other hand
$$\dot{r}_{H}(t)=-c\frac{\ddot{a}}{\dot{a}^{2}}>0\iff\ddot{a}<0$$
so why should it be increasing if we know that the universe is expanding? Is it due to $\Lambda$?
Cause I would say that
$$r_{H}=\frac{1}{\dot{a}}=\frac{1}{aH}\propto t^{1-\alpha}$$
with $\alpha=\frac{2}{3(1+w)}$, so I get an increasing $r_{H}$ only for $-1<w<-1/3$. So for a MD or RD universe I'd expect a decreasing radius.

For some cosmological models it might increase or decrease...I dont think that is a problem...

Ah good to know, my notes don't specify it. If you know some example it would be great. Thank you
